# How can I put php variables with quotes into onclick?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I cannot figure out how to properly put php variables inside of onclick so that it does not cause some kind of error :( I have no clue what direction to go. It seems like whenever there is quotes, it causes this error. Perhaps there are other characters that will cause problems too. The page does load, it is just when I press my "infoIconButtonImage" that the error occurs. Here is what I have tried:

```
while($stmt->fetch()) 
{                       
    $shortDescription = preg_replace("/\r\n|\r|\n/",' ', $shortDescription);
    $longDescription = preg_replace("/\r\n|\r|\n/",'<br/>', $longDescription);
    $price = preg_replace("/\r\n|\r|\n/",' ', $price);


    echo "<div class=\"iconButtonContainer\"><img class=\"infoIconButtonImage\" src=\"Images/item_info_button_image.png\" alt=\"\" onclick=\"showMoreItemInfo(this, '$price', '$imageUrl', '$shortDescription', '$longDescription')\"></div>";
}
```

I have taken out parts of code I don't think are necessary. Here is the data and error:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would recommend getting rid of the inline javascript. You can put everything in a javascript block and at the top of that block you can send all your php variables to javascript using `json_encode()`. You could of course also use `json_encode()` for inline javascript...

Comment: I am very new, not really sure how to do that :S

Comment: Guessing you want something like `onclick<?php echo whatever ?>`

Comment: Mixing three different languages in a single line of code is just *begging* for quoting errors...

Comment: @Mihai i'm not sure I understand... I already echo at the start of the line so isn't the whole statement already recognized as php?

Comment: Sorry missed that.Probably missing a ) put that javascript into an online validator,see what comes up.

Comment: @Mihai - no, it's because there are apostrophes inside the text being echoed out. The PHP is fine in itself, but the generated JS is seeing the apostrophes as string delimiters

Comment: @David [Welcome to hell](http://static.mmzstatic.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/hell.gif) ;)

Comment: jokes apart I would start by wrapping it all in single quotes `'`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
echo "<div class=\"iconButtonContainer\"><img class=\"infoIconButtonImage\" src=\"Images/item_info_button_image.png\" alt=\"\" onclick=\"showMoreItemInfo(this, '" . $price . "', '" . $imageUrl . "', '" . $shortDescription . "', '" . $longDescription . "')\"></div>";
```